# Html page not reading external javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Having trouble connecting my external JavaScript to my HTML page. Pretty sure I have saved the file **script.js** in the correct folder, the path is correct but it has not worked. Not too sure why. Pretty sure I have the correct coding but when I paste it on too my html page nothing seems to work either when I run it.

Not alerts pop up when its suppose too i.e only numbers for postcode or must have @ in email etc. It might be my JavaScript but I'm not too sure as I am new to this.

Here is my external JavaScript:

```
function validateForm() {
    if (document.getElementById("name").value == "") {
        alert("You cannot leave this field blank. Please enter your name");
    } else {
        alert("field OK");
    }


    if (document.getElementById("address").value == "") {
        alert("Please enter your address");
        document.getElementById("address").focus();
        return false;
    }

    if (isNaN(document.getElementById("postcode").value.length < 4)) {
        alert("Your postcode is not valid");
    } else {
        alert("You have entered your postcode correctly");
    }


    if (document.getElementById("email").value.length < 5 || document.getElementById("email").value.indexOf("@") == -1) {
        alert("Please enter your email min 5 chars and include @ symbol");
        document.getElementById("email").focus();
        return false;
    }


    {
        if (isNaN(document.getElementById("creditcard").value.length < 16)) {
            alert("Please enter your Creditcard number");
        } else {
            alert("Please enter a valid credtcard number");


        }
        alert("Thank you for your submission!");
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: How you include java script file in your html page?

Comment: check your console for errors

Comment: Right clikc page, go to `View Source`, click on the javascript link and see if the code is visible or if you get 404 error

Comment: Is the above one you are using? If yes then check "{" braces.

Comment: you either need to add one more `}` at the end of your code, or remove the free-hanging `{` one. You will also need to call your the `validateForm` method from somewhere..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, there's one bracket too much.

```
{  // <---- remove this.
    if (isNaN(document.getElementById ("creditcard").value.length < 16))
```

Comment: Guess I just missed something out but now all seems working. Thanks.